# Completely stuck on where to start on programing

Tags: javascript

I've been given a task to produce a webpage which solves the quadratic formula. Talking to friends they have said the simplised way is to learn java script and build the webpage. I have been learning the language on code academy and that's fine but where and how do I i write in my own code and execute it for java script? All I have been using so far is the editor page on code academy. Im completely lost in where to go next

Comment: Open up Notepad on your computer, write in there, and open it with your browser. Or just use WolframAlpha.

Comment: Ya just start with any code editor and you are good to go in the browser. you can also see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125431/how-to-start-programming-in-windows

Comment: You need to read some basics of [HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Introduction)...

Answer (score 1):

Write the code in a simple notepad or wordpad file (TextEdit for Mac), and then save it with a .html extension. Now when you open it, it should open in your browser by default. Be sure to properly enclose your javascript in `<script>` tags.

Comment: So say I get a piece of code that I written in code academy thats javascript and in enclose it in <script> tags I it should simply run?

Comment: It should. You might need to enclose it in <html> tags as well.

Comment: Okay and In code academy there are two tabs for coding where it tells me to code in, while notepad only is one tab to code. Do I just put the code in there as well?

Comment: I wrote this in notepad but nothing came up: <script>


prompt("What is your name?");

<script>

Comment: Use Teemu's link regarding HTML basics. You need to you a closing tag: <script> prompt("What is your name?"); </script>